# Windows, how to render to video scan-out memory directly?

Tags: winapi, opengl, directx

On Windows and optimally using OpenGL, can I render directly to video scan-out memory (hdmi port of the graphics card)? No buffer swapping, no windowing system - directly rendering to the buffer from which pixels get copied to the wire.
Ultimately I want to implement a scanline-racing prototype.
But it seems the default way of creating an opengl context on windows involves creating a pixelformatdescriptor and as far as I understand it that just allocates an offscreen buffer (doubly buffered if requessted), the content of which is then copied by the window manager and composited before somehow set as the video scan-out memory.

Comment: "*a scanline-racing prototype*" I fail to see exactly how this requires any particular video output. You're building an image; whether that process directly writes to the video output is kind of irrelevant to how you build that image.

Comment: You mean hdmi? I just added it for completeness because I assumed it might be relevant. Looking at VR headsets, the VIVE for example, it can run in ‚extended mode‘, in which the headset is just treated as a secondary monitor, or ‚direct mode‘. In direct mode the headset is not recognized/shown by windows as an additional display and rendering performance is better - so I believe they are able to bypass the desktop window manager in this mode, which in windows 7 and up takes control of vsync and copying data to read-out memory. Connection in this mode is still via hdmi

Answer (score 1):

> On Windows and optimally using OpenGL, can I render directly to video scan-out memory (hdmi port of the graphics card)?

In the days before Windows-Vista DWM/Aero you'd just create a window and create a single buffered OpenGL context. Back in those days, the client regions were memory views of the actual scanout buffer.

Of course OpenGL already back then didn't specify any relationship between when drawing commands were issued and when or in which order they were executed; as long as the *"the result looks exactly as-if things were executed in this order"* rule was adhered to, any reordering was fair game. So already then you couldn't practically use OpenGL to race the beam. And neither you could with Direct3D, I might add.

What you was possible however is using DirectDraw in *exclusive* mode, which would actually give you direct access to the whole of the scanout buffer, in a way that'd you'd actually could race the beam.

But given the modern graphics stacks, even with that racing the beam no longer works, because:

> No buffer swapping, no windowing system - directly rendering to the buffer from which pixels get copied to the wire.

Well, if you can get hold of ancient hardware that actually works that way. These days it's all about swap chains. On current generation Intel integrated graphics for example, even in text mode the display wouldn't even update if something wasn't pumping the swap chain.

Of course you can still issue a swap while mid frame-scanout, thus tearing the frame. (which is part of the reason, why to this date double buffering in X.Org usually tears moving pictures (video)).

---

In your comment:

> Looking at VR headsets, the VIVE for example, it can run in ‚extended mode‘, in which the headset is just treated as a secondary monitor, or ‚direct mode‘

This direct mode is nothing special. Two things are happening:

1. The HMD is simply hidden from the selection of displays you can expand the desktop to.
2. To access the display a direct mode graphics context (using DirectX or Vulkan) is created, which mostly behaves as a fullscreen window, complete with a swap chain.

Vulkan (that text referring to an older version of Vulkan but still applies):
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.30.0/linux/vkspec.chunked/ch29s03.html

DRM leases on Linux:
https://keithp.com/blogs/DRM-lease/

Comment: is VK_KHR_display supported on Windows? is there an equivalent for Open GL?

I don't quite see why racing the beam wouldn't be possible? If I can render directly to the scan-out memory, and if I can flush the graphics pipeline using glFlush, I can divide the target buffer for example into 4 horizontal stripes, render to stripe 1, flush(), render to strip 2, flush etc..

Comment: @user1282931: glFlush doesn't do what you think it does. All it does is telling the OpenGL implementation that you're done submitting for the time being, and that you expect it to go to work in the not so distant future. glFinish implies a flush and blocks until the implementation is done executing the commands, but again the timing is not precise. SwapBuffers is similar in that it will either return immediately and calling the next OpenGL call that would modified the backbuffer committed to swap would be modified (Intel) or it blocks until the swap happened (Nvidia).